# noUiSlider: how to allow to slide till the end, even if the end value is less than step value

Tags: nouislider

I am creating a slider with the following config

```
step: 60,
range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 1439
}
```

Now if i have `max: 1339` instead of `1440` then how to allow the slider to step 59 as last step i.e till the end.

currently its steps 60 and says invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple ranges to the slider, and only set a step of `60` for the first range.

[Documentation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/#section-non-linear-step)

```
range: {
   'min': [0, 60],
   '90%': [1380],
   'max': [1439]
}
```